# PHP class object as other class parameter

Tags: php

I have a problem, I need to rewrite my c++ program in PHP, I have very little experience.

Here is my code:

```
class Variable {
    public $power;
    public $shortcut;
    public $value;
    public function __construct($a, $b, $c) {
        $this->shortcut=$a;
        $this->value=$b;
        $this->power=$c;
    }
};

class Formula {
    Variable var1;
    Variable var2;
    Variable var3;
    $sign;
};
```

Formula class have 3 parameters which are objects of Variable class, How do I write something like that in PHP?

Comment: What is `$sign`? Also, your forumla variables should have `$` in front of them: `Variable $var1;`

Comment: You just did, except for a few syntax errors. I don't really know, what's the issue here.

Comment: $sign is another parameter of Formula class

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't support typed attributes of a class. You can create accessor methods and mutator methods to control of attributes type. For example:

```
class Formula {

    /**
     * @var Variable
     */
    private $var1;

    /**
     * @var Variable
     */
    private $var2;

    /**
     * @var Variable
     */
    private $var3;

    public function setVar1(Variable $value)
    {
        $this->var1 = $value;
    }

    public function getVar1()
    {
        return $this->var1;
    }

    public function setVar2(Variable $value)
    {
        $this->var2 = $value;
    }

    public function getVar2()
    {
        return $this->var2;
    }

    public function setVar3(Variable $value)
    {
        $this->var3 = $value;
    }

    public function getVar3()
    {
        return $this->var3;
    }
};
```

Comment: PHP doesn't support typed attributes of a class _yet_. But it will as of 7.3. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2 for details.

Comment: @Gordon, yes but it will be in future